# Find matching key in two associate arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, match, associate

I'm using codeigniter and I have a returned associated array from db like this:

```
 $result = ['name'=>'john', 'author'=>'smith', 'year'=>2011 ];
```

And a long list of translated title for the keys saved as an array like this:

```
$lang = ['name'=>'名字', 'author'=>'作者', 'year'=>'年份', ... ];
```

I wanted to compare the key of $result to $lang, if a key was used in $result, get its translated title.  And at the end, construct an array including all three English title, translated title, and the value:

```
$lang_result = ['name'   =>['名字', 'john'],  
                'author' =>['作者', 'smith'],  
                'year'   =>['年份', 2011] ]

$data['result'] = $lang_result;
```

I'm storing into this format because once I passed in these data into views, I wanted to be able to call each one by name

```
echo "{$result['name'][0]}:  {$result['name'][1]} "; // 名字: john
echo "{$result['author'][0]}:  {$result['author'][1]} ";
```

So far I could only achieve this by using foreach -> switch statement

```
$lang_result = [];

foreach ($result as $key=>$value ) {
    switch （$key）{
        case 'name':
            array_push ($lang_result, [ $key => ['名字', $value] ]);
            break;

        case 'author':
            array_push ($lang_result, [ $key => ['作者', $value] ]);
            break;
    }

}
```

But as the translated array gets longer, the switch statement will be ridiculously out of hands. What is a better way to simplify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dan mentioned `array_merge_recursive` may be what you want. In case you have other logic you need to implement here it is unrolled:

```
$result = ['name'=>'john', 'author'=>'smith', 'year'=>2011];
$lang = ['name'=>'名字', 'author'=>'作者', 'year'=>'年份'];

$lang_result = [];
foreach ($result as $key=>$value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $lang)) {
        $lang_result[$key] = [$lang[$key], $value];
    }
}

// these are the same (for now)
print_r($lang_result);
print_r(array_merge_recursive($lang, $result));
```

Comment: After a few experiments, I found that the foreach loop has more control. array_merge_recursive will output all the keys from the two array even though sometime the result array only has a few keys.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `array_merge_recursive`

```
$newArray = array_merge_recursive($result, $lang);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the keys you want into an array and then do it like so.

```
$lang_result = array();
$result = ['name'=>'john', 'author'=>'smith', 'year'=>2011 ];
$lang = ['name'=>'名字', 'author'=>'作者', 'year'=>'年份'];
$keys = array('name','author','year');
foreach($keys AS $key){
   if(isset($result[$key]) && isset($lang[$key])){
        $lang_result[$key] = array($result[$key],$lang[$key]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something? You said foreach loop has more control. Why am I not upvoted? I am the 2nd answerer after Dan. New users don't get credit?

Comment: I'm so sorry because I don't have 15 reputation point, so I couldn't upvote answers.